# Hover menu not showing

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with the drop menu for a website I made not working. The site can be accessed here: http://tlcompanioncare.com/

The menu item to have the drop down is Services.

I've been looking at this for a couple hours now, but I know I overlooking something. If anyone can give me a hand that would be great.

HTML code

```
<nav class="nav">
      <ul class="sf-menu" data-type="navbar">
        <li>
          <a href="./">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.php">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="services.php">Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="pdf/services.pdf">Questionnaire</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.php">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
.tablet .sf-menu li + li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.sf-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sf-menu:before, .sf-menu:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.sf-menu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.sf-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.sf-menu > li + li {
  margin-left: 34px;
  position: relative;
}
.sf-menu > li + li:before {
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  left: -19px;
  top: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sf-menu a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sf-menu {
  font-family: "Tims New Roman", serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sf-menu a {
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.sf-menu > li {
  text-align: left;
}
.sf-menu > li > a {
  color: #b5c1a7;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a, .sf-menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #485b66;
}
.sf-menu > li.active > a {
  color: #485b66;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #485b66;
}

.sf-menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 239px;
  left: 10px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  background: #485b66;
  z-index: 2;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.sf-menu ul > li > a {
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #fff;
}
.sf-menu ul > li.sfHover > a, .sf-menu ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dedede;
}
.sf-menu ul > li .sf-with-ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sf-menu ul > li .sf-with-ul:before {
  content: '-';
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sf-menu ul ul {
  position: static;
  top: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.sf-menu ul ul > li > a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.sf-menu ul ul > li > a:before {
  content: '-';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.lt-ie9 .sf-menu ul ul > li > a:before {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.sf-menu ul ul > li.sfHover > a:before, .sf-menu ul ul > li > a:hover:before {
  width: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .sf-menu ul ul > li.sfHover > a:before, .lt-ie9 .sf-menu ul ul > li > a:hover:before {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sf-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't comment that you are going to answer. Just answer. Comments should be used to clarify the question. @AravindhanR

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website, your services **li** should have position relative, add it and your menu dropdown will show.

Comment: Thank you @nitrex - But that does not help. I already have position relative assigned to the element: .sf-menu > li + li

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

.sf-menu > li > a

Padding-left 15px to 30 px and right 15 px to 80px

I have tried in your website through the chrome inspect working fine

Comment: Thank you @Aravindhan - but that did not fix the issue.